# Sitecore _path field returns NULL in Solr index

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Solr index for Sitecore.

However, the search result always gives back null for _path field.

It was working on Lucene. Does Solr needs special treatment?

Below is the glass mapper property:

```
[IndexField("_path"), TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
        [SitecoreIgnore]
        public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ID> EntityPath { get; set; }
```

And the SOLR schema has entry below:

```
<field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Did you try with `stored="true"`?

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks

Comment: Will move comment to answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your "store" setting to true:

```
<field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

The stored attribute will make sure that your original value is kept in the index for retrieval. Otherwise you can search in the field, but not fetch it.